# mi pequeño programa no resta correctamente

Tags: python-3.x, vscode, operador-de-conversión

soy  nuevo  en este  foro y tambien en este  mundillo de la programacion, soy  novato llevo 3 semanas  aprendiendo python, y estoy tratando de crear un pequeño programa:
se trata de  una pizzeria, el usuario ingresa  por pantalla un monto de dinero y el programa basicamente toma  los pedidos del usuario, una pizza de peperoni por ejemplo y los añade  a una lista, seguido  se le da la opcion al usuario para que escoja  un complemento si lo desea, y es aqui donde esta mi problema, en el programa  muestro por panatalla  el valor del producto y el restante (ej: si la pizza cuesta 7 euros ese valor se resta al monto que  el usuario ingreso por pantalla) todo va  bien hasta que doy la  opcion de escoger ingredientes ( estos tienen el valor en centimos) al restar  lo que cuesta añadir ese ingrediente lo hace mal y me da un resultado erroneo y ese fallo se ve  reflejado al final cuando muestro el cambio que recibio el cliente, perdonden si no me  supe explicar muy bien pero les adjunto el codigo:

```
# definiendo variables:
dinero = float(input('introduce el monto a  utilizar: \n € '))
MONTO_INICIAL = dinero

#pizzas
peperoni = 5.60
hawayana = 7.00
quesos = 7.50
#ingredientes
queso_chedar = 0.50
pollo = 0.50
champiñones = 0.80
# Restante
total = 0
ticket  =  []
# titulo
print('BIENVENIDO A \'JORGE\'S PIZZA')
print('--------------------------------')    

#menu
while True:
    print(f'1. pizza mediana peperoni: € {peperoni} ')
    print(f'pizza mediana hawayana: € {hawayana}')
    print(f'pizza  mediana 4 quesos: € {quesos}')

    pregunta = int(input('elija la pizza que desea  ordenar, usando el numero que le corresponda \n ->'))

    if  pregunta == 1:
        print(f'mediana peperoni -> € {peperoni}')
        dinero -= peperoni
        total += peperoni
        ticket.append(f'peperoni -> {round(peperoni,2)}')
        print(f'tienes  disponible: € {round(dinero,2)}')
        break
    
    elif pregunta == 2:
        print(f'mediana hawayana -> € {hawayana}')
        dinero -= hawayana
        total += hawayana
        print(f'Tienes  disponible {round(dinero,2)}')
        ticket.append(f'hawayana -> € {hawayana}')
        break

    elif pregunta == 3:
        print(f'mediana 4 quesos -> € {quesos}')
        dinero -= quesos
        total += quesos
        print(f'tienes disponible -> € {round(dinero,2)}')
        ticket.append(f'champiñones -> € {round(quesos,2)}')
        break

    else:
        print('opcion no valida, porfavor  elija una opcion del 1 al 3')
        

# escogiendo ingredientes: 
while True:
    print(f'1.agregar complemento extra queso chedar -> € {queso_chedar}')
    print(f'2.agregar complemento pollo -> € {pollo}')
    print(f'3.agregar complemento champiñones -> € {champiñones}')
    print('4.No agregar ningun complemento')

    pregunta2 = int(input('¿le gustaria agregarun complemento extra?, porfavor elija una de las siguientes  opciones:\n'))

    if pregunta2 == 1:
        print(f'complemento queso chedar € {queso_chedar}')
        dinero -= queso_chedar
        total += queso_chedar
        print(f'tiene  disponible -> € {dinero}')
        ticket.append(f' complemento queso chedar -> {queso_chedar}')

    elif pregunta2 == 2:
        print(f'complemento pollo -> € {pollo}')
        dinero -= pollo
        total += pollo
        print(f'tiene disponible -> € {pollo}')
        ticket.append(f'Complemento pollo -> € {pollo}')


    elif pregunta2 == 3:
        print(f'complemento de champiñones -> € {champiñones}')
        dinero -= champiñones
        total += champiñones
        print(f'tiene disponible -> € {champiñones}') 
        ticket.append(f'champiñones -> € {champiñones}')

    else:
        print('no se agregara  ningun complemento.')
        break

#imprimiendo ticket de  compra:
if total <= MONTO_INICIAL:
    print('No disponede suficiente dinero para realizar su compra, porfavor vuelva al ordenar.')

else:

    print('------ JORGE\'S PIZZA--------' )
    print(f'su cambio es de: {round(dinero, 2)} \n Muchas gracias por su compra! \n QUE LO DISFRUTE!')

    for i in ticket:
        print(f' -> {i} ')
        break
```

se que  mi codigo es  muy malo y seguramente tengo muchos  fallos, pero me harian un gran favor si pudieran decirme porque al añadir ingredientes no lo resta correctamente del valor introducido por el usurio al principio del programa, disculpen si me extendi demasiado, un saludo!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Antes que nada, NO somos un FORO, somos un sitio QA (Preguntas y Respuestas). Por otro lado, no es necesario que pidas disculpas ni mucho menos, todos hemos sido principiantes. Lo más importante: tienes código y eso mucho más de lo que la mayoría de nuevos usuarios puede presumir, por lo tanto, felicitaciones. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour], además puedes leer [mre]. Haz clic en [edit] y explica con mayor detalle el problema en cuestión. Por ejemplo: ¿Qué montos introduces? ¿Qué valores son calculados? ¿Qué valor debería mostrar?, etc. Saludos

Comment: hola, ok muchas gracias  por tu respuesta, voy a rehacer el codigo para resumirlo y describir mejor mi problema, un saludo!

Comment: Cambiar `if total <= MONTO_INICIAL:` por `if total > MONTO_INICIAL` será eso????

Comment: @Yussef,@Mauricio Contreras, muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer, hice la respectiva correccion, aunque mi problema estaba, en que cuando debia ponerla variable dinero para que me devolviera el restante, en su lugar le puse la variable del ingrediente, por eso me devolvia el valor del ingrediente  como resultado y por ello no hacia la resta correctamente, Muchas gracias a  los 2  por sus respuestas y su tiempo  un gran saludo! y de nuevo gracias chicos.

Comment: if pregunta2 == 1:
        print(f'complemento queso chedar € {queso_chedar}')
        dinero -= queso_chedar
        total += queso_chedar
        print(f'tiene  disponible -> € {dinero}') -> aqui, puse queso chedar en lugar de dinero 
        ticket.append(f' complemento queso chedar -> {queso_chedar}')

Comment: Jorge, para responder a tu pregunta, debés utilizar la sección de _respuestas_. Esta es la sección de _comentarios_. Como te han dicho, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. No olvides además [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Tal como te han dicho, [es.so] es un sitio QA (**Preguntas** y **Respuestas**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te he mirado los errores más sencillos que tienes y coincido con los anteriores y te escribo todo lo que he visto:

```
print(f'2. pizza mediana hawayana: € {hawayana}') #Te falta la etiqueta 2.
print(f'3. pizza  mediana 4 quesos: € {quesos}') #Te falta la etiqueta 3.
print(f'tiene disponible -> € {dinero}') #dinero i no pollo
ticket.append(f'champiñones -> € {champiñones}')#dinero i no champiñones
if total > MONTO_INICIAL: # No has montado bien la condición no es <=
#       break =======> No puedes escribir break, ja que sólo escribe una vez
```

Comment: hola muchas gracias por la ayuda, si , efectivamente hice esas correcciones antes, revisando el codigo me percate que habia puesto mal las variables justo lo que has dicho, los chicos de alla arriba tambien me ayudaron, apenas hoy vi tu comentario, de todas formas muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, un saludo.